# why does not this query work?

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net

I added a textbox and a button as the below

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Email'e Göre Silin"></asp:Label>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Sil" />
```

but my query isn't work for these.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-VQUBBVP\\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog=UgurBocegiDatabase; Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblMessage where Email = '"+TextBox1.Text+ "' ", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have tried adding as below .tostring method but it didn't work again.

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from tblMessage where Email = '"+TextBox1.Text.ToString()+ "' ", con);
```

and the query works in sql server as in the below

```
delete from tblMessage where Email = 'gs213'
```

what is the problem?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks

Comment: Never, ever do this at home, kids.

Comment: Read [ask] and elaborate on "does not work".

Comment: Learn to use parameters for queries.  Munging query strings can introduce very hard to find syntax errors (and makes the code prone to SQL injection attacks).

Answer (score 0):

this would work.

instead of string concatenation you may use parameters as below.

```
using (SqlConnection connection =
                    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DEFAULT"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand("delete from tblMessage where email = @email", connection);
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("email", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                {
                    Value = TextBox1.Text
                });
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```